# r shiny: Load data in to form fields from previously persistent stored data

Tags: r, forms, shiny, storage, persistent

Gist from Dean Attali: https://gist.github.com/daattali/c4db11d81f3c46a7c4a5
In this example: data can be entered, submitted and saved (persistent data storage). You can see the submitted data in a table that appears after submitting. By time the table is growing with different entries. So far there is no possibility to load the data in the submitted form to change or update the submission?!

My question: Is it possible to load the data from previous submissions not only to the table but also to the fields (name, used shiny, r num years)?
I would like to update the entries and save them back.
I am aware of CRUD. I am wondering if it is possible with Dean Attali's persistent data storage example. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")

# Save a response
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type ----
saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
}

# Load all previous responses
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type ----
loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
    sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })
    
    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })
    
    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now exactly found what I was looking for: https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-crud-app/
This post shows you step by step how to build a Shiny app that lets you create, update and delete data in a table.

You can see the app in action here: https://gluc.shinyapps.io/crud

The full source-code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/gluc/d39cea3d11f03542970b

Now the next step is to combine: submit, new, delete and save to a for example csv file.
I will try it out!