# I want to generate a table of inputs based on a dataframe such that if I change anything in that table, the dataframe is modified. - R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a dataframe with 3 columns :-

- -has_subscribed (0,1)
- -gender(factor - male, female),
- -Address (text)

and I want to generate a table of inputs based on this dataframe such that if I change anything in that table, the dataframe is modified. I want the has_subscribed to be presented as checkbox, gender to be presented as dropdown and address to be presented as text_input. How can I do that in R Shiny? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic example:
Create a directory called `responses` in your working directory and then apply this code:
And please see my post and my answer [r shiny: Load data in to form fields from previously persistent stored data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329561/r-shiny-load-data-in-to-form-fields-from-previously-persistent-stored-data) to extend this kind of task:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("has_subscirbed", "gender", "address")

# Save a response
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type ----
saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
}

# Load all previous responses
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type ----
loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput("has_subscribed", "Has Subscribed", FALSE),
    selectInput("gender", "Gender", c("Female", "Male")),
    textInput("address", "Address", ""),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })
    
    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })
    
    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
  }
)
```

[image]